# How can I start Oracle as a lightweight process?

Tags: oracle, continuous-integration

I have OracleDB running in a CI pipeline in a docker image.  With each test it is started and then shutdown.  It's purely there because Django tests expect a real database.

However it takes a couple of minutes each time to start and shutdown.  Is there a way to make it start really quickly and use less memory?

Comment: I think this time limit is default.

Comment: To my knowledge Oracle does not have a "lightweight" configuration. You could perhaps allocate less memory, but this would likely not improve the startup time and would very likely hurt performance of your pipeline. Oracle has a lot of background processes to spin up and consistency checks and such to run, and that takes cpu. The biggest difference you could probably make to startup time would be to increase the available cpu cores.

Comment: Start Oracle on the host and leave it running?

Comment: Hm, I’d love to have a hosted oracle database that I just use for CI testing, but there are all these isolation issues that come with that.